# break loop in angularjs in view part

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to skip last value in 
ng-options="sport.sport_id as sport.name for sport in sports"

```
{"sport_id":1,"name":"a"},{"sport_id":2,"b":"c"},{"sport_id":3,"name":"d "},{"sport_id":"4","name":"e"}]
```

I mean not to show e value skipped that one

Comment: Punctuations. This question needs a lot more of those.

Comment: Michael please take a glance one time more

Comment: You can use filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the solution to slice out the last item in sports instead of using ng-if:

```
<select ng-options="sport.sport_id as sport.name for sport in sports.slice(0, -1)" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Comment: `ng-if` is on the `<select>` and since `$index` doesn't exist the `<select>` will never be shown

Comment: Fixed. I now use a slice on sports instead of ng-if. Sorry!